# backbone.stickit not updating with model change

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing, backbone-model

I have a backbone.sticket binding attached to a model associated with a `mainView` view:

```
bindings: -> {
        ".some-class": "someAttribute",
    }
```

and the following template

```
<div class="some-class"></div>
```

The attribute populates correctly, but when I attempt to edit `someAttribute` in the browser console:

```
router.mainView.model.attributes.someAttribute = "TEST"
```

nothing changes in the binding, even though typing

`router.mainView.model.attributes.someAttribute`

into the browser console returns `"TEST"` as expected.

Should I expect the content of the div to be changing in the browser as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticket is presumably event based and Backbone events don't work that. If you edit a model's [`attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes) by hand, nothing in Backbone will know what happened so no events will be triggered. If you want events to be triggered, you need to use [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set):

```
router.mainView.model.set('someAttribute', 'TEST')
// or
router.mainView.model.set({ someAttribute: 'TEST' })
```

Either of those should generate `"change"` events and that's probably what Sticket uses to hook itself up.